# Store array data to mySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to store an array to mySQL table. My Table has 6 columns (question, choice1-4, correct). I use an array to save data entered from HTML form. I use a for loop to get each data of each form. (each form is a question with 4 choices and a correct answer). My PHP code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "q-a";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// store question and answer
for ($i=0, $i < count($_POST['q1'], $i++){
    $question = $_POST['q1'][$i];
    $choice1 = $_POST['c1'][$i];
    $choice2 = $_POST['c2'][$i];
    $choice3 = $_POST['c3'][$i];
    $choice4 = $_POST['c4'][$i];
    $correct = $_POST['ca'][$i];    

    $store_question = "INSERT INTO quiz (question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, correct) VALUES ('$question', '$choice1', '$choice2', '$choice3', '$choice4', '$correct')";
    $result_get_question = mysqli_query($conn, $store_question);
}  

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Nothing was happened.  Can someone spot where  am I wrong. Do we need to use serialize() function ?

Comment: Can i  have a look on  html  part

Comment: Please share html. Are you unsing array for name field like <input type="text" name="c1[]" >. How you posting form? like AJAX submit or normal form submit. Please share html

Comment: I use a normal form submit using POST method. Scenario is like: I want to make a simple quiz with the question and choices from a form input <input name="q1[]">

Comment: for example: I want to store 2 question: from 2 <input name="q1">. but it only save the first value of array to database

Answer (score 0):

*Mistake-1*: you missed a `)` in your `count()` function in `forloop`

*Mistake-2*: you have used incorrect syntax in the loop. You have to use `;` instead of `,`

Updated Code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['q1']); $i++){
    $question = $_POST['q1'][$i];
    $choice1 = $_POST['c1'][$i];
    $choice2 = $_POST['c2'][$i];
    $choice3 = $_POST['c3'][$i];
    $choice4 = $_POST['c4'][$i];
    $correct = $_POST['ca'][$i];    

    $store_question = "INSERT INTO quiz (question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, correct) VALUES ('$question', '$choice1', '$choice2', '$choice3', '$choice4', '$correct')";
    $result_get_question = mysqli_query($conn, $store_question);
}
```

Comment: before for loop. Can you please add `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);die()` and share the output.

Comment: Array
(
    [q1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thủ đô của Việt Nam là
            [1] => 1 + 2 bằng?
        )

    [c1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hà Nội 
            [1] => 3
        )

    [c2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TP HCM
            [1] => 4
        )

    [c3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Huế
            [1] => 5
        )

    [c4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Đà Nẵng
            [1] => 6
        )

    [ca] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hà Nội
            [1] => 3
        )

)

Comment: it only store the first value of array to database

Comment: can you just echo the results to see if the array elements are accessed in the loop exectution?

Comment: can you check it via Teamview?

Comment: Are you able to see the output ?

Comment: each array has 2 values but it only store the first value to database.